# ci pagination shows same pages on all links

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I am having the pagination kept in my codeigniter project. The links are all shown in the view page. But whichever link that I clicked is getting me to the same page...
The following is my controller code..

```
public function newsletter()
    {
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $config = array();

        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "index.php/welcome/newsletter";
        $this->load->model('newsletter_model');
        $total_row = $this->newsletter_model->record_count();
        $config["total_rows"] = $total_row;
        $config["per_page"] = 1;
        $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
        $config['num_links'] = $total_row;
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '&nbsp;<a class="current">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';

        $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
        $config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        if($this->uri->segment(3)){
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ;
        }
        else{
        $page = 1;
        }
        $this->load->model('newsletter_model');
        $data["results"] =      $this->newsletter_model->fetch_data($config["per_page"], $page);
        $str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data["links"] = explode('&nbsp;',$str_links );

        $this->load->model('newsletter_model');
        $data['rm_newsletter'] = $this->newsletter_model->get_rm_newsletter();        
        $this->load->view('newsletter/newsletter',$data);
    }
```

The following is my view code:

```
foreach ($lt_newsletter as $letter) {
echo $newsletter['nl_newsletter']; }

<div id="pagination">
   <ul class="pagination">
      <?php foreach ($links as $link) 
      {
       echo "<li>". $link."</li>";
      } ?>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

And finally in my model:

```
public function fetch_data($limit, $id)
    {
    $this->db->limit($limit);
    $this->db->where('nl_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get("ins_newsletter");
     if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
     {
       foreach ($query->result() as $row) 
       {
        $data[] = $row;
       }
     }
    }
    public function record_count() 
    {
     return $this->db->count_all("ins_newsletter");
    }
    public function get_rm_newsletter()
    {
        $data = $this->db->query('SELECT nl.* FROM ins_newsletter nl ORDER BY nl.nl_id DESC');
        return $data->result_array();
    }
```

In my browser all the links(1,2,3,4) are shown clearly, but after I click on every link(1,2,3,4), it is showing the same page with all the records. For presently, I have 4 records in my database and it lists all. Kindly point me where am i going wrong...! Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So, you are getting all the records in all the pages?

Comment: yes i have all the records shown but do not know where to give offset for page numbers

Comment: A refresher course on pagination https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/codeigniter-from-scratch-day-7-pagination--net-7023

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the error is in your model, I see that you have a

> $this->db->where('nl_id', $id);

but in the function in the controller you pass two parameters

> $data["results"] =      $this->newsletter_model->fetch_data($config["per_page"], $page);

this are the pagination values, one for quantity of record,(not variable), and the other for the page you are passing (1,2,3,etc.)

So, you have to add another parameter to make the `where`. See this [link in pagination does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44782003/link-in-pagination-does-not-work) and if you have some other problem can tell me.