# link in pagination does not work

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am trying to make a pagination and I almost get it, but when I change one page to another **(click page 1, later click page 2)** does not work, but when I do manually **it works**. That is becouse when I click in the links in my browser show this:`&page=40`, and manually I only put the `40`. I do not know why is that.

**this is my Controller**

```
function Test ($value){
if($value =='1'){
  $config['per_page'] = 20;
  $config['num_links'] = 10;
  $config["total_rows"] = $this->db->get('normas')->num_rows();
  $data['query'] = $this->db->get('normas', $config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(4));
  $this->pagination->initialize($config);
  $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

 $this->load->view('template/general_template/template', $data);
    }
}
```

**My view**

```
<?php 
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    echo '<p>'. $row->norma.'</p>';
    } 
echo $links;
?>
```

Please help!!, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change `$config['page_query_string']== FALSE` becouse I had it in `TRUE`

> $config[‘page_query_string’] = TRUE;
>
> By default, the pagination library assume you are using URI Segments, and >constructs your links something like:
>
> http://example.com/index.php/test/page/20
>   If you have $config['enable_query_strings'] set to TRUE your links will >automatically be re-written using Query Strings. This option can also be >explicitly set. Using $config['page_query_string'] set to TRUE, the pagination >link will become:
>
> http://example.com/index.php?c=test&m=page&per_page=20

I found this in the Codeigniter documentation
[CodeIgniter documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, seems like you're missing the

```
$config['cur_page'] = $this->uri->segment(4);
```

and

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://yoursite.com/index.php/test/page/';
```

take a look at https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html

Comment: I do what you said, but still not working, `$value` is a parameter in my function.

Comment: cur_page is the current page of the pagination. If you are clicking the second pagination link, cur_page is 2, the third, cur_page is 3 and so on. So I asumed that $value holds the current pagination value. Like I said a more complete code would be helpful.

Comment: this is all my code, I do not know what more put in, the `(...)` is my load view

Comment: Thank´s it works now, I only had to change in my configuration `$config['page_query_string'] = FALSE`,  I had it in **TRUE**, but now I have another problem, **First** do not shows.

Comment: Try changing the default values for $config to accomplish what you are looking for.